# How to create a popup within another popup

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Can we create a popup within a popup.

I have a thumbnail image and when I click on it, it popup with large image using fancy box. Now I want in such a ways that, when I hover over a point in the large image it should popup another image over it.

How to make this possible. If anyone have example with a link then it would be more helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to place a fancy box inside another fancy box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735918/how-to-place-a-fancy-box-inside-another-fancy-box)

Comment: I don't have an answer to your specific question, but this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taa1953/MhnVA/) may get you started. The initial FancyBox contains a valid HTML document displayed in an `iframe`. The FB will popup and `alert`. As you can see, I commented out the call to FancyBox. The problem is an error that `$` is not defined. I assume that is because the document in the `iframe` does not load jQuery (or FancyBox for that matter). Linking to a resource is more than I want to tackle right now. Also, as suggested by @BassaWalter, you can try the `hover` event to fire the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could attach a hover event to the specific section. For example

```
 $('.hover-section').hover(function() {
       // do what you want to here
 });
```

[jQuery hover reference](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)